# How to run PostgreSQL LIKE query with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, escaping, sql-like

Suppose i want to run query like this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE $1";
$r = pg_query_params($dbconn, $q, array("%" .  $ss . "%"));
```

The problem may arise if user has supplied string with `%` or `_` for `$ss`. How can i tell engine to not consider `%` and `_` in `$ss` as special symbols?

---

For now my approach is

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE $1 ESCAPE '\'";
$r = pg_query_params($dbconn, 
         $q, 
         array("%" . str_replace("%", "\%", str_replace("_", "\_", $ss)) . "%"));
```

But what if escape character (`\`) is the last one in the string, then appended `%` will be escaped as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first suggestion is to eschew `LIKE`.  Just do:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE position($1 in name) > 0;
```

Then you don't have to worry about special characters.

You can use `ESCAPE` . . . but you need something that is not in the string, say `~`.

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE $1 ESCAPE '~'
```

Then when you bind the parameter:

```
$r = pg_query_params($dbconn, $q,
                     array("%" . str_replace(str_replace($ss, "_", "~_"), "%", "~%") . "%"));
```

You can escape the escape character by doubling it.  That is just another `str_replace()`:

```
$r = pg_query_params($dbconn, $q,
                     array("%" . str_replace(str_replace(str_replace($ss, "~", "~~"), "_", "~_"), "%", "~%") . "%"));
```

Alternatively, make the use of `LIKE` a *feature*, and let the users put in wildcards, because they then have more powerful search capabilities.

Comment: Any character could be in the string and in any position, that is one of my concerns

Comment: @Yola . . . I modified the answer.  But on second thought, see the first solution.  `LIKE` is not the right operator for what you want to do.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!